# A simple speech to introduce a song to audiences

Tags: sentence-choice

I'd like to find common sentences to introduce a song. Could you please suggest me some? Can I say these ones? I can hardly know if it sounds odd

- "I'd like to present to you a song of..."
- "I'm going to submit to you a song of..."

Comment: And what is the context?  Are you an MC (emcee), walking on stage before the audience to announce the next part of some performance?  You can always say, "And this is a song by..." or "And now we'll hear a song..."

Comment: I'm the person to sing. Thank you. I'm going to say "This is a song... Hope you enjoy it". Is it fine?

Comment: please don't mind about why would I have to introduce the song's name, just in case of precaution

Comment: A short introduction with the name of the song and when/why it was written would be fine in that case.  "This is a song... " or "Here is a song..." are both acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

What I have mostly seen and done is that if it is your own song (your lyrics and composition), you can say
*"Hello everyone. **I'd like/I'm going** to **perform/present** my composition in front of you. Hope you like it."*
or
If it some other song, you can simply say
*"Hello everyone. **I'd like/I'm going** to sing the song ABC. Hope you like it."*